# Задача на решение ребуса

Tags: математика, арифметика

Всем привет, встретилась с такой задачей:

```
Умница Наденька и хулиган Вася составили по одному примеру
на сложение, а потом заменили цифры буквами (одинаковые цифры
— одинаковыми буквами, разные - разными). У Наденьки получились
осмысленные слова:
СОВА+КРОВ+РЕКИ+ИКАР+ЕВРО+ПАНК+ПЕС=КИРОВ,
а у Васи — какая-то абракадабра: АНСН + НИИП + ВСПЕ = ВСНЕИ.
А чему равна сумма КИРОВ + ВСНЕИ?
```

я выяснила, что о=0(так как у нас всего 10 букв, причем на 9 из них начинаются числа в ребусе), но теперь абсолютно не представляю, как решать задачу. Сначала думала, что к точно равно 3, но потом поняла, что это не точно. Помогите пожалуйста с решением, заранее спасибо)))

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что он не относится к тематике RuSO

Comment: если бы задача была по матиматике, то наверно решать следовало логически. например, какие 3 четырехзначных числа в сумме дают пятизначное и т.д. здесь же в программировании напрашивается перебор или случайные значения (но чтоб не нарушалось условие задачи)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ну, раз мы программисты, сайт программистский — а по заветам Кнута из тома 4а, такое решается простейшим перебором. Для 10 символов вариантов не более 10! = 3628800, что для компьютера — раз плюнуть.

```
СОВА+КРОВ+РЕКИ+ИКАР+ЕВРО+ПАНК+ПЕС=КИРОВ
```

имеет 13 решений,

```
АНСН + НИИП + ВСПЕ = ВСНЕИ
```

два, так что, надо понимать, они заменяли цифры буквами одинаково (из условия это не очевидно).

Общее решение одно, в нем

```
ВСНЕИ = 15794;  КИРОВ = 34201
```

так что сумма их равна `ИЕЕЕС` — 49995...

Comment: если вам не сложно, можете пожалуйста более четко пояснить решение

Comment: Пояснить, что такое "перебором"? Пишем программку и перебираем все 3628800 возможных вариантов подстановки 10 цифр для 10 букв. И проверяем, выполняется ли заданное условие...

Comment: да, верно) спасибо

Comment: Мы вы мегамозг...

Comment: Если хочется немного ускорить процесс, то можно обратить внимание, что буквы СКРИЕПАНВ быть нулем не могут, что приводит нас к О=0, и необходимости проверять перестановки 9 цифр для 9 букв, то есть 362880 вриантов

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов Можно, конечно. Имеет ли смысл — вопрос второй. Я когда-то, когда с упомянутым томом 4А работал, написал себе раз и надолго :) программку, которой просто передаю любую арифметику, включая возведение в степень. Она решение для жуткого выражения `(АНСН + НИИП + ВСПЕ - ВСНЕИ)**2 + (СОВА+КРОВ+РЕКИ+ИКАР+ЕВРО+ПАНК+ПЕС-КИРОВ)**2 = 0` находит менее чем за полсекунды (при этом основное время уходит на разбор арифметики... для сравнения `АНСН + НИИП + ВСПЕ = ВСНЕИ` решается на порядок быстрее. Так что, как мне кажется, для десятичной системы счисления оптимизации излишни...

Comment: @Harry может, Вы и правы.... :)